# SQL query union best practice

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to classify data as I extract it from a table. the data has a history kept via "valid_from" and "valid_to" date fields in each row.

I want to extract the data and qualify it as follows:

```
NEW => WHERE CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN valid_from AND (valid_from + 1 MOTNH)
CURRENT => WHERE CURRENT_DATE > (valid_from + 1 MOTNH)
RETIRED => the rest of the rows, so the "dish_id" items not in the tables above, BUT 
           returning the values from the row containing MAX(valid_to) date.
```

Am I doing this the best / more efficient way? Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT
    menu_table.dish_id,
    menu_table.dish_title,
    menu_table.marketing_desc,
    menu_table_status.rrp_inc_gst,
    menu_table_status.lowest_rrp,
    menu_table_status.highest_rrp,
    'n' as status
FROM 
    menu_table,
    menu_table_status
WHERE
    CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN menu_table_status.valid_from_date AND DATE_ADD(menu_table_status.valid_from_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
    AND CURRENT_DATE < menu_table_status.valid_to_date
    AND menu_table.dish_id = menu_table_status.dish_id
UNION
SELECT
    menu_table.dish_id,
    menu_table.dish_title,
    menu_table.marketing_desc,
    menu_table_status.rrp_inc_gst,
    menu_table_status.lowest_rrp,
    menu_table_status.highest_rrp,
    'c' as status
FROM 
    menu_table,
    menu_table_status
WHERE
    CURRENT_DATE > DATE_ADD(menu_table_status.valid_from_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
    AND CURRENT_DATE < menu_table_status.valid_to_date
    AND menu_table.dish_id = menu_table_status.dish_id              
UNION
SELECT
    menu_table.dish_id,
    menu_table.dish_title,
    menu_table.marketing_desc,
    menu_table_status.rrp_inc_gst,
    menu_table_status.lowest_rrp,
    menu_table_status.highest_rrp,
    'r' as status
FROM 
    menu_table,
    menu_table_status
WHERE
    menu_table_status.valid_to_date
    AND menu_table.dish_id NOT IN (SELECT inside_table1.dish_id
                       FROM menu_table_status AS inside_table1
                       WHERE CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN inside_table1.valid_from_date 
                                                          AND inside_table1.valid_to_date)
    AND menu_table_status.valid_to_date = (SELECT MAX(inside_table2.valid_to_date)
                           FROM menu_table_status AS inside_table2
                           WHERE inside_table2.dish_id = menu_table_status.dish_id)
    AND menu_table.dish_id = menu_table_status.dish_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without much looking at it you are certainly confusing dates in your last where clause. Anyhow, your statement is way to complicated. Simply select all records (which you want to do anyhow) and look at each record's dates to decide for the status to give:

```
SELECT
  menu_table.dish_id,
  menu_table.dish_title,
  menu_table.marketing_desc,
  menu_table_status.rrp_inc_gst,
  menu_table_status.lowest_rrp,
  menu_table_status.highest_rrp,
  CASE 
    WHEN
      CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN menu_table_status.valid_from_date AND DATE_ADD(menu_table_status.valid_from_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
      AND CURRENT_DATE < menu_table_status.valid_to_date
    THEN 'n' 
    WHEN
      CURRENT_DATE > DATE_ADD(menu_table_status.valid_from_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
      AND CURRENT_DATE < menu_table_status.valid_to_date
    THEN 'c'
    ELSE 'r'
  END as status
FROM menu_table
INNER JOIN menu_table_status ON menu_table.dish_id = menu_table_status.dish_id;
```

BTW: Please don't use that old join syntax where you list all tables comma-separated. It's prone to errors, which is why there is a "new" syntax available as of 1992.

EDIT: I've spotted your error. Instead of checking for `CURRENT_DATE < menu_table_status.valid_to_date` you check for `menu_table_status.valid_to_date` only thus treating the date as a boolean value, which is something special in MySQL.

One more remark: When unioning sets that are distinct (yours are because of different status letters)use UNION ALL, not UNION. UNION is used to remove duplicates. Why have the dbms check all your records when you know there are no duplicates?

Comment: Hi Thorsten, thanks for the reply! 1992 was kinda the last time I worked with SQL on an IBM mainframe! I like your approach, but will your "ELSE r" piece cause to return all other rows, which will include multiple rows for the "dish_id"s that do not satisfy the first two CASE statements? All the same I tried running it and I got a syntax error at the "INNER JOIN" statement because of the COMMA after the table name!

Comment: Hi Thornstem, I have added "ORDER BY menu_table.dish_title ASC" to order dishes alphabetically, but the order is not working. What am I missing? Many thanks again!

Comment: I've removed the comma. Sorry, that was a cut & paste mistake. The order by should work; I see no reason why it shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten, you helped me a lot! To complete the query I needed to add "GROUP BY menu_dishes_status.dish_id HAVING MAX(menu_dishes_status.valid_to)" to your suggestion to get the latest entry for 'r' rows. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to perform this in one go, I would recommend to extract step one into a temporary table, and then define step two as left join on dish_id with that temporary table, where dish_id is NULL:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE step1 AS (
SELECT
    mt.dish_id,
    mt.dish_title,
    mt.marketing_desc,
    mts.rrp_inc_gst,
    mts.lowest_rrp,
    mts.highest_rrp,
    (
        if(CURRENT_DATE<DATE_ADD(mts.valid_from_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH),
           'n', 'c')
    ) as status
FROM 
    menu_table mt 
    JOIN menu_table_status mts ON mt.dish_id=mts.dish_id 
    WHERE CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN mts.valid_from_date AND mts.valid_to_date-1
);

SELECT step1.*
UNION
SELECT
    mt.dish_id,
    mt.dish_title,
    mt.marketing_desc,
    mts.rrp_inc_gst,
    mts.lowest_rrp,
    mts.highest_rrp,
    'r' as status
FROM
    menu_table mt 
    LEFT JOIN step1 s1 on s1.dish_id=mt.dish_id WHERE s1.dish_id is NULL
    JOIN menu_table_status mts ON mt.dish_id=mts.dish_id;
```